# Azure URL Shortener Unauthorization Issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, postman

I have deployed URL Shortener on Azure through functions, I am trying to access function URL via postman GET/POST methods but I am getting 401 unauthorized error though "authLevel" is  "anonymous" in JSON.

Is there anyway to authenticate with Azure functions? I have created function key as well but still getting 401.

This is my Azure function shortener URL

```
https://shortenertools***.azurewebsites.net/api/UrlShortener?
```

My function key

```
p43I-wfaw3TvfFtIWK5gVLof9jAH6Ny8RQW1Mn3_aE7KAzFubcPq0Q==
```

I would really appreciate your support.

Thanks

Atif Inayat

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

1. Not only in the `function.json`, make `AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous` in the Function Code or in the Azure Portal Function App Settings:

[image]
2. If Authorization Level is anonymous, then the function key passing in the Function URL is not necessary.
3. When the Authorization Level is function, then Function Key should be passed over the Function URL. If not, then 401 Unauthorized Status code will be the result.